# how to check the array of values to perform the condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two tables users and providers.

1.Users id's and providers vendorId should be equal.

2.if no record is found for the users id . Insert a new record for the users in providers table.
I went through some websites I unable to find the solution without using the loop.
Is possible to do without loop.

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "steve",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Albert",
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Antony",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Williams",
    age: 22,
  },
];
```

```
const provider = [
  {
    vendorId: 1,
    status: "act",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    vendorId: 3,
    status: "inactive",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    vendorId: 5,
    status: "act",
    description: "",
  },
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: The statement isn't clear. Do you want to add a entry to the vendor table if a user with a vendor Id is not in it?

Comment: yes. If the user's table id not found in vendors's table should add new entry to vendors table

Comment: So you will have to add a loop to check if userId exists in user table and then it is present in vendor table if not then add the userId to vendor table

Comment: yes, I want to avoid looping . if it possible

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this... Not sure why you are wanting to eliminate loops in this case.  This flattens the syntax, but loops are still present.

I'm guessing you'll want to do some transformation on the user that gets stuck into the providers array so the data matches. That is not done here.

```
var users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "steve",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Albert",
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Antony",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Williams",
    age: 22,
  }
];

var providers = [
  {
    vendorId: 1,
    status: "act",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    vendorId: 3,
    status: "inactive",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    vendorId: 5,
    status: "act",
    description: "",
  }
];


//If no record found for the users id. Insert a new record for the users in providers table
function isUserAProvider(userId){
    return providers.find(p => p.vendorId == userId) != undefined;
}

users.forEach(u => isUserAProvider(u.id) ? null : providers.push(u));
```

Comment: forEach mybe slow up the response if large amount of data

Comment: @AsZik Of course yes, But you have one and only option `Loops` to check each and every record. To deal with large set of data, Use chunks or parallel processing.